# Write data to the ArrayList with the JButton JAVA

Tags: java, events, arraylist, actionlistener, jlist

What I want is, when the user clicks the button, the data entered in a `Textbox` or `JList` or removed from anywhere, goes into an array list.

I do not want to build a database! I just want the data to be stored while the user uses the application. I've tried everything, but it seems that the event button requires a certain difficulty, the code should not be taken seriously, it is only meant for analysis.

The important thing is to write data to array with the press of a button.
ex:

```
btnSaveToArray.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        ArrayList recordArray=new ArrayList(); 

        // This variable receiveList, receives value a given selected from a JList, is far from good.
        String receiveList = userList.getSelectedValue().toString();
        // The variable recordArray capture this value, the goal is that this variable store it.
        recordArray.add(receiveList); 

        // these two lines to see if I recorded the same roof but're angry, it just returns me one record element.
        System.out.println(recordArray.toString()); 
        // these two lines to see if I recorded the same roof but're angry, it just returns me one record element.
        System.out.println(recordArray.size());   
    }
```

I tried to print out the contents of the array, to see if user input is recorded but it does not print out anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is whenever the user clicks on OK button, your actionPerformed(ActionEvent) method will be executed. Each time the method called, you are creating an ArrayList, which do not contain the previous selections. So, the ArrayList has to be an instance variable. Each time the user clicks on OK button, you simply add the selection to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep outside your List from the ActionListener

```
  ArrayList recordArray=new ArrayList(); 

  btnSaveToArray.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        String receiveList = userList.getSelectedValue().toString();  

        recordArray.add(receiveList); 

        System.out.println(recordArray.toString()); 
        System.out.println(recordArray.size());  
  }
```

Comment: Happy to hear it..........

Answer (score 0):

You should establish the arraylist outside of the action listener, and only perform the add function inside the listener, like this:

```
public class Recorder {

    public ArrayList recordArray;

    public Recorder() {
        recordArray = new ArrayList();
        JButton btnSaveToArray = new JButton.... //whatever you are doing here
        btnSaveToArray.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                String receiveList = userList.getSelectedValue().toString();
                recordArray.add(receiveList);
                showTheRecords();
        });
    }

    public void showTheRecords() {
        for (int i = 0; i < recordArray.size(); i++ ) {
            System.out.println(recordArray.get(i).toString()); //get 
        }
        System.out.println("Record count: " + recordArray.size());
    }

}
```

Comment: @RamomMoura - no problem.  A vote up says thank you as well ;)